# possibility of same cluster and different hash values

Tags: data-structures, cluster-analysis, hashtable

Is there a possibility to have two items in the same cluster that they have different hash values? Can someone explain it in terms of data structures and algorithms?

Comment: I believe you should read about the [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) for the start.

Comment: What definition of cluster, what definition of hash are you using? Say a MD5 hash, the chance is extremely high that non-duplicate values have a different hash, independent of a cluster structure...

Answer (score 0):

I think fuzzy algorithm will answer the question. Fuzzy algorithm states that each data object belongs to every cluster with some weights such that sum of weights equal to 1.

For refernces:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering

Answer (score 0):

It depends on collision resolution strategy implemented in a structure
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

In case of "Open addressing" strategy - yes,
you can have two items with unique hashes in a clustering collision because of a previous collision was solved by taking a slot that new item is probing
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#/media/File:Hash_table_5_0_1_1_1_1_0_SP.svg